# Performance difference in clustering algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, matlab

I have a similar problem area as mentioned [Trajectory Clustering: Which Clustering Method?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70106/trajectory-clustering-which-clustering-method) . As per suggestion to use dynamic time warping for aligning the time series, are there any differences in performance when a data is clustered with k means and Gaussian mixture model (GMM) or in general when to employ k means and GMM for clustering?Under what circumstances should k means and GMM be chosen for clustering? Also, in the response mentioned how is the centroid calculated from (x,y) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both k-means and GMM need to be able to compute a sensible **mean** of the cluster, and are designed for Euclidean distance.

This is not really trivial for trajectories; you may need to do a lot of interpolation.

Instead, use a distance based clustering that can handle DTW distances; such as DBSCAN, OPTICS and good old hierarchical linkage clustering.

See also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70867/how-to-get-the-centroid-of-one-cluster